# Can't update data in Vue.js using event.target.href

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vue-props

I am trying to update my Vue.js data (**linkClicked**).

I have URLs being passed into my Vue component as props from Laravel. These props are attached to multiple anchor tags on the page with various URLs from the props. Wherever there is an external link, I have attached a click event which calls a method (**showModal**). For example my anchor tags look like this:

```
<a @click.prevent="showModal($event)" :href="extcontacturl">Contact Us</a>
```

In this method, I am logging the **$event.target.href** in the console, and can confirm that I am seeing the correct links in the console when clicked on. So the props are working fine. My script code looks like this:

```
export default {
  props: [
    "extcontacturl",
  ],

  data() {
    return {
      linkClicked: undefined
    };
  },

  methods: {
    showModal($event) {
      this.linkClicked = $event.target.href;
      console.log($event.target.href);
    }
  }
};
```

However **linkClicked** in my data is not being updated at all, and I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

What I am expecting is for **linkClicked** to update to the URL string represented by the props. For example if **extcontacturl** is set as "https://www.google.com/contact", then I expect linkClicked to update to this URL when the contact link is clicked.

Comment: why not directly set it inside a tag ? like <a @click.prevent="linkClicked = extcontacturl" :href="extcontacturl">Contact Us</a>

Comment: I tried doing it this way just now, but the same issue occurs (nothing updates)

Comment: are you sure your extcontacturl has a value ?

Comment: Yeah it was showing the correct values when I do a console.log or alert, just wouldn't assign to the data.

Comment: It seems that nothing wrong with your code. Can you just change your props into this ?

 

    props: {
                extcontacturl: {
                    type: String,
                    default:'test'
                },
            },

Comment: Strangely it seems to work fine now, although I never changed the code. I recompiled app.js multiple times and never worked as it should after a few hours. Possibly was caching something?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `this` in the template.

It should be like that :

```html
<a @click.prevent="showModal($event)" :href="extcontacturl">Contact Us</a>
```